# Restating a number theoretic statement algebraically

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I'm attempting to restate the following number theoretic statement algebraically. I'm sure it's been done before but I wanted to see if I could do it myself as I only have an undergraduate understanding of algebra.

Statement (number theoretic): If $a, b, c$ are integers and $p$ is an odd prime such that $p \nmid a$, then the solutions of the congruence $ax^2 + bx +c \equiv 0 \:(mod \:p)$ are given by the solutions to $2ax \equiv -b+y \:(mod \:p)$, where $y$ runs through a complete solution to $y^2 \equiv b^2 - 4ac \equiv 0 \:(mod \:p)$. A complete solution has $1$ element if $p \mid b^2 - 4ac$. Otherwise, $0$ or $2$ solutions.

Statement (algebraic): If $a, b, c$ are elements of the finite field $\mathbb{Z}_p$ where $p$ is an odd prime and $a$ is not the zero element, then the solutions to $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ are given by $x = (2a)^{-1}(-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac})$ if and only if $\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}$ exists in the field.

My main concerns are whether or not I should have stated the conclusion as a biconditional statement and whether or not I need to specify that $\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}$ must exist in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ in the field. Any feedback/tips will be appreciated.

Comment: How about saying this. If $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}=0$, then there is one solution, else if $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\in(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^*$, there exist two solutions, else $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ does not exist in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and there is no solution.

Comment: @DisplayName I think I might have too many moving parts in my statement, so to speak. I think it might be better to consider a, b, c integers and the polynomial P(x) with solutions given by the quadratic formula since we are guaranteed that those exist in some field. Then have the actual statement be that the solutions exist in the field iff the discriminant is a square in the field. This would correspond nicely to the congruence statement and be much easier to read/prove.